# Displaying Error Message in Bootstrap Modal in Spring MVC Project

Tags: spring-mvc, bootstrap-modal, display

**Is it possible to display "User with this username does not exist" Error Message in Bootstrap Modal in Spring MVC Project through the controller?**

**login.jsp**

```
<div class="modal-body">
<form id="register-form" role="form" autocomplete="off" class="form"
    method="POST"
    action="${pageContext.request.contextPath }/recoverPassword">

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i
                class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope color-blue"></i></span> <input
                id="email" name="username" placeholder="your username"
                class="form-control" type="text"> ${error}
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
        value="${_csrf.token}" />
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
        Send email link</button>

</form>
```

**controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/recoverPassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)
public void sendingEmailForForgot(@RequestParam("username") String username) {

    // Check whether email exists in DB
    System.out.println(userDAO.getUserByName(username));
    System.out.println(username);
    if (userDAO.getUserByName(username) == null) {

        System.out.println("This ID does not exists");
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("error", "wrong");

    } else {
        System.out.println("mail sent to your id");
    }

    // If exists then hash and send url link
    // else error

}
```

I have validated username whether if exists, but how to display that error on same currently opened modal?

If not possible through controller please share any other way to do so.

Comment: I think if you wanted to change the currently open Modal you would need to do it via AJAX

Comment: Hi can you throw some more light?

Comment: Without getting response from web service how can you show anything in bootstrap modal? And which version of spring are you using that is very important.

Comment: that's the question, I have made the response in a controller which validates whether this username exists, the problem is I want to keep bootstrap modal open if there is no such username and if it is there then i will redirect to homepage view. So how to do these two things parallelly is my question.

Comment: Implementation-Version: 4.3.4.RELEASE version I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it through AJAX, still don't know if possible through the controller. Works fine for me, I have used this:

```
function doAjaxPost() {
    // get the form values
    var name = $('#name').val();
    var education = $('#education').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: contexPath + "/AddUser.htm",
        data: "name=" + name + "&education=" + education,
        success: function(response){
            // we have the response
            if(response.status == "SUCCESS"){
                userInfo = "<ol>";
                for(i =0 ; i < response.result.length ; i++){
                    userInfo += "<br><li><b>Name</b> : " + response.result[i].name +
                    ";<b> Education</b> : " + response.result[i].education;
                 }
                 userInfo += "</ol>";
                 $('#info').html("User has been added to the list successfully. " + userInfo);
                 $('#name').val('');
                 $('#education').val('');
                 $('#error').hide('slow');
                 $('#info').show('slow');
             }else{
                 errorInfo = "";
                 for(i =0 ; i < response.result.length ; i++){
                     errorInfo += "<br>" + (i + 1) +". " + response.result[i].code;
                 }
                 $('#error').html("Please correct following errors: " + errorInfo);
                 $('#info').hide('slow');
                 $('#error').show('slow');
             }
         },
         error: function(e){
             alert('Error: ' + e);
         }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following trick worked for me
 1. put ${error} in p tag with unique id
 2. On login.jsp page load,check if innerHtml of p tag is empty.
 3 If it is not empty open the login modal.

```
function modelopen(){
var temp = document.getElementById("errormsg").innerHTML;
  if(temp!==""){
    $('#modallogin').modal('show');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:
1) RestController instead of Controller (I think that this is way you solved this)
2) You can use validations and return your error as part of BindingResult https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html
3) Use exceptionHandler

Answer (score 0):

1. ```js
   function errorshow() {
   const input1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
   const input2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
   const div = document.getElementById("erroM");
   if (input1 == '' && input2 == '') {
      div.innerHTML = "hey";
      setTimeout(() => {
       div.remove()}, 2000);
    }}
   ```

   ```html
   <!doctype html>
   <html lang="en">

       <head>
           <!-- Required meta tags -->
           <meta charset="utf-8">
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

           <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
               crossorigin="anonymous">
                <title>Erorr Show in Modal</title>
       </head>

       <body>
           

   <!-- Modal -->

   <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
           <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header">
                   <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                   </button>
               </div>
               <form>
                   <div class="modal-body">
                       <div id="erroM"></div>
                       <div>
                           <input id="input1" type="text">
                           <input id="input2" type="text">
                           <input id="input3" type="text">
                       </div>
                   
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="errorshow()">save</button>
                   </div>
               </form>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
   <!-- Button trigger modal -->
   <button id="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">Click</button>
           <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
           <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
           <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
               crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
               crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
               crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

           <script src="main.js"></script>
       </body>

   </html>
   ```